# Tag proposal: [weak-references]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

A [weak-references](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-references) tag would be suitable for:

- [What is the right way to “remove” Reference from it's ReferenceQueue?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28534/what-is-the-right-way-to-remove-reference-from-its-referencequeue)
- [Observer pattern in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23288/observer-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I have edited that new tag into the first question.  Once the edit is accepted, it should be ready.

**Update**: The new tag has been created.